# nginx upload progress combined with normal request

Tags: nginx

I have a good virtual host for nginx that works well without using the nginx upload module.
*When I add upload progress into this my upload request.* How can I solve this? i need to upload my files using `/?r=upload` or `/upload?foo=bar` and track upload progress data using `/progress` or something else.

```conf
# static9-localhost.sweb
server {

        # upload limit
        # upload_limit_rate 10240;

        # request size limitation
        client_max_body_size 500m;
        client_body_buffer_size 64k;

        # document root
        root /path/to/webapp/static/public/;

        # index file
        index index.php;

        # server name
        server_name static9-localhost.sweb;

        # rewrite rules
        rewrite "^/thumbnail/([A-Za-z0-9]{12})/(.*)/.*$" /index.php?r=thb&unique=$1&prm=$2 last;

        # /
        location @frontcontroller {
                # expires
                expires max;

                # disable etag
                if_modified_since off;
                add_header 'Last-Modified' '';

                # mvc rewrite
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        }

        # upload progress
        location /upload {
                upload_pass @frontcontroller;
                track_uploads proxied 600s;
        }

        # progress
        location = /progress {
                report_uploads proxied;
        }

        # error pages
        error_page 404 /index.php?r=404;
        error_page 403 /index.php?r=403;
        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /index.php?r=500;

        # php5-fpm
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9003;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # logs
        access_log /path/to/webapp/logs/static_access.log;
        error_log /path/to/webapp/logs/static_error.log;
}
```

For the above virtual host my upload request to `/upload/?X-Progress-ID=QLiFKnG5A81K` freezes. what is the problem?

I need request such as `/?r=blahblah` to work well also if I send my upload file into `/upload` using `/?r=upload`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are two modules in your config: upload module, and upload progress module. The upload module directives seems OK to me, but I think you are missing the `upload_progress <zone_name> <zone_size>` directive on the `location /upload` block, which enabled upload progress tracking, as stated on the nginx documentation (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule#upload_progress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through my configs for a working example. I use upload modules and upload progress in such a way:

```
    upload_progress proxied 4m;
    ...
    server {
        ...

        location ^~ /progress {
                report_uploads proxied;
        }

        location ^~ /services/ {
               rewrite ^/(.*?)/?$ /$1.php break;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
               include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ^~ /upd/ {
               upload_pass   /services/upload/;
               upload_pass_args on;
               upload_store_access group:rw;
               upload_store /tmp;

               set $upload_field_name file;
               upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
               upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";
               upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";
               upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
               track_uploads proxied 30s;
       }
  }
```

Also look at the firebug Net tab. Look if your code get a correct json output. Maybe the problem is in client-side really.